# Escape puzzle: why does grep ignore escaping of single quote?

Tags: grep, escaping

(*other quote/grep questions are about bash interpretation, this is not*)

Apparently `grep` handles escaped single quotes differently than other escaped regex characters, but I don't understand why.

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.25

$ cat data
a']
b']
c']
d]
e\']

$ cat patterns
a']
b\'\]
c'\]
d\']
e\']

$ grep -Ef patterns data
a']
c']
```

Because `c` is matched but `b` isn't, apparently grep does not interpret an escaped single quote `\'`as a single quote. But as what then?

- `d` isn't matched, so it is not ignored.
- `e` isn't matched, so it is not taken literally

TIA for solving this x-mas mystery! PS. Yes in this case I can use -F for literal matching, but my application requires regex.

Comment: The problem, in a simpler formulation, is why does `echo "d']" | grep -E "\d"` match `d`, and `"\]"` match `]`, but `"\'"` does not match `'`? I have taken the liberty of reframing this question to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332749/46316).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\'` in GNU tools means "end of string". See http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html:

```
Additional GNU Extensions
....
The anchor \` (backtick) matches at the very start of the subject string,
while \' (single quote) matches at the very end.
```

Don't ask me why they introduced that as it seems to be exactly the same as `$`.